# exponential generating function, labelled trees

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to get a feeling for combinatorial classes and generating functions. Does anybody know a good source with many solved exercises?
And I have the following problem:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the class of vertex-labelled trees that have one vertex of even degree and every other vertex has odd degree. By $a_n$ we denote the number of trees in $\mathcal{A}$ with n vertices.

Argue directly that $a_n=0$ for $n$ even. 
Let $A(z)= \sum \limits_n \frac{an}{n!}z^n$ be the exponential generating function $\mathcal{A}$. Derive an implicit formula for $A(z)$ and determine $a_n$ from this formula. Verify that indeed every coefficient with even index is zero.

In the moment I have no idea how to start this problem. Can anybody give me tips how solve such a problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985352/) might be relevant (root has even degree), as might be [OEIS A0336778](http://oeis.org/A036778).

Comment: I have already seen this MSE link. But I'm not sure how to get it that I have only one node with even degree..

Comment: If you select one node to have even degree (the root) and attach a set of trees with even out-degree then the root has even degree and the the other nodes odd degree. so there is just one node of even degree. The lower nodes are attached to a single parent and have an even number of children, so the total degree is odd.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985352/labelled-rooted-tree-with-odd-degree so i can use the generating function $H(z)$ from here?

Comment: $F(z)$ is rooted, even degree at root, odd at rest. $H(z)$ is rooted, odd degree at all nodes.

Comment: So the generating function $F(z)=\frac{z}{2}(e^{F(z)}+e^{-F(z)}$ is exactly the generating function I need? Sorry for my confusion

Comment: It would seem so. Good luck.